# Unable to deserialize valid JSON into a class with generic IEnumerable<T> property

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I am currently struggling to deserialize received JSON into a DTO object which has `IEnumerable<T>` data property. Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and System.Text.Json 4.7.0.

Below is displayed the JSON

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "alternateId": "2cc688d6-cc51-4501-9320-9e5b6e0b8710",
      "name": "random1",
    },
    {
      "alternateId": "e1c14f81-12fa-4ed8-b5ab-e1f4b9f25401",
      "name": "random2",
    }
  ],
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "pageSize": 2,
  "resultCount": 2,
  "sortColumnName": "Name",
  "orderByType": "Ascending"
}
```

And I am trying to deserialize this data into the following Dtos by using these commands:

```
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PagedResponse<OutputDTO>>();
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var responseData2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResponse<OutputDTO>>(responseString);
```

The first `ReadAsAsync` approach deserializes all other properties correctly except the data. Second, responseData2 deserialization produces only empty properties.

Dto classes:

```
public class PagedResponse<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; }

    public PagedResponse()
    {
    }

    public PagedResponse(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }
    public int? ResultCount { get; set; }
    public string SortColumnName { get; set; }
    public OrderByType OrderByType { get; set; }
}

public class OutputDTO
{
    public Guid AlternateId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your `OutputDTO` class look like? Deserializing to generic classes works - `List<T>` is such a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Data` property has no public setter, so the serializer won't assign it.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set;  }
```

In the second case you should also pass the serializer the option to ignore property name casing:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResponse<OutputDTO>>(json,
    new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

Comment: The missing public setter was the key, my mistake. Now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your json has trailing commas (`"name": "random1",` `"name": "random2",`), if you can't change it you will need to allow that explicitly, for example:

```
 JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResponse<OutputDTO>>(json, 
     new JsonSerializerOptions {AllowTrailingCommas = true});
```

Also set `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `true` on `JsonSerializerOptions` or mark properties with `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` with corresponding names(also you will need to add public setter to `Data` property on `PagedResponse` cause currently [internal and private property setters and getters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson) are not supported). For example :

```
public class PagedResponse<T>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("data")]
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: although the better option would be to use _valid json_ instead, without trailing commas.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann agreed, but sometimes it out of our control =( .

Comment: there is _always_ the option of physically going to the person who screwed up such a simple thing as creating valid json and shout in their face that they ought to fix their faulty code. even _if_ that doesn't help with solving the problem, it helps with personal satisfaction ;)

Comment: The trailing commas in the array are no problem though, it deserializes just fine without this setting.

Comment: @CodeCaster was throwing exceptions on my machine, maybe there is also global settings to change this behavior.

Comment: Great point about the invalid JSON, however, my bigger mistake was the missing public setter... Anyways good info on how to deal with the trailing commas.